# AWS cloudwatch alarm for RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-cloudwatch

Is there a way to make an alarm on cloudwatch for my RDS instances based on % free disk (i know i can turn on enhanced monitoring and that metric is there, but i can't use those metrics on cloudwatch alarms) 
if not is there a good way out ?

Answer (score 0):

RDS doesn't report percentage of disk space free, but it does report the amount of free space available. See the list of CloudWatch metrics available for your RDS instances [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/rds-metricscollected.html).

You would need to create alarms on the `FreeStorageSpace` metric reported by each of your instances.

Comment: yep, i know there is no such metric on cloudwatch. But my problem is if you have a DB instance with 50 GiB allocated, an alarm that goes on if the  FreeStorageSpace <= 5 GiB makes sense. But if u raise the allocated space to 300GiB or more the alarm no longer appears to be a good threshold value so everytime you raise the storage, the alarm need to be update.  An % value would be great in this cases

Comment: Yes but that doesn't exist. File a request with AWS if you want them to add it.

Comment: there must be a workaround it seems like a common case, there is a small effor to solve, but it's so impractical to keep modifying an alarm just cause you raised the storage size. But anyways will do @Mark

Comment: Another option would be to use a more full-featured monitoring and alerting solution. I've had good luck with Datadog (I have no relationship with them other than a satisfied customer) and it can definitely do percentage-based alarms. I'm sure there are other tools available as well.

Answer (score 0):

See [an option using Enhanced Monitoring and log metrics enter link description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58657063/how-do-i-get-totalstoragespace-or-usedstoragespace-metric-from-aws-rds/62559625#62559625). Basically you can turn on enhanced monitoring for RDS and then parse the JSON logs to get the `usedPercentage` value for the storage filesystem. This can be turned into a log metric that can be associated with an alarm.